# Dragablz TabablzControl: How to implement IManualInterTabClient so that new tabs can be programatically added

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I need the ability to programmatically add a tab to a Dragablz TabablzControl.  I've read that I should implement IManualInterTabClient which just exposes Add(object) and Remove(object) but I've had no luck getting this to work.

Can anyone provide and example of how this is to be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When tearing away a new tab, I discovered that trying to add an additional tab while the newly created window was still in motion was the issue.  Once the new window is no longer being dragged and is fully painted, adding a new tab worked as expected.